# why the Django admin login page throwing FieldError?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Something strange happened. I have created the custom user model. It was working properly until today. And I have no idea what has gone wrong. When I launch the admin page to login, I see below error after I click on 'login'. I use 'email' as an username

```
FieldError at /admin/login/
Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field. Choices are: auth_token, auth_token_set, contact, dob, email, employee_code, first_name, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, password, user_permissions
```

- I tried to remove the migrations file and re-run the migrations, but no use.
- Then I deleted the App completely and configured each and everything from scratch. Yet the same error.

[Here](https://dpaste.com/G25AW54H9) is the full Error stack

### models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, AbstractUser
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('Enter the email before proceeding'))

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, password=password, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user


class NewEmployeeProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    employee_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    dob = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _('staff status'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'),
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. '
            'Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
        ),
    )

    objects = AccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'contact']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.email)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your traceback you seem to be using the package `drf_registration` and using `drf_registration.auth.MultiFieldsModelBackend` as the authentication backend. This package by default uses the list `['username', 'email',]` (See [Settings (drf_registration - GitHub)](https://github.com/huychau/drf-registration#settings)) as the possible fields that will be provided as the username to filter the user model for performing authentication.

Your custom user model has no field as `username` hence this gives you an error.

To change the fields used by this backend you need to set the setting `LOGIN_USERNAME_FIELDS` as follows in `settings.py`:

```
LOGIN_USERNAME_FIELDS = ['email',]
```